# Disable Cut and Copy in context menu in Monaco editor

Tags: monaco-editor

I am using monaco-editor, i see that cut and copy is added in the context menu in later versions. i want to remove these two options from context menu. Please let me know how can i achieve it?

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Hide individual items with CSS

I tried this code in the browser and it worked.

```js
// Hide from cut on
.context-view li.action-item:nth-child(n + 9) {
    display: none !important;
}

// Show command palette
.context-view li.action-item:last-child {
  display: flex !important;
}
```

#### Disable the entire menu with API

```js
monacoOptions = {
  // other options
  contextmenu: false
}
```

See Docs on [`IEditorConstructionOptions` > `contextmenu`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.ieditorconstructionoptions.html#contextmenu)

Comment: Hi, I want to show context menu but disable some options from context menu. I want to hide copy, cut and paste options from contextmenu and i dont want to disable context menu completely.

Answer (score 3):

#### Full Code

```js
import * as actions from "monaco-editor/esm/vs/platform/actions/common/actions";

let menus = actions.MenuRegistry._menuItems
let contextMenuEntry = [...menus].find(entry => entry[0]._debugName == "EditorContext")
let contextMenuLinks = contextMenuEntry[1]

let removableIds = ["editor.action.clipboardCopyAction", "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction"]

let removeById = (list, ids) => {
  let node = list._first
  do {
    let shouldRemove = ids.includes(node.element?.command?.id)
    if (shouldRemove) { list._remove(node) }
  } while ((node = node.next))
}

removeById(contextMenuLinks, removableIds)
```

#### Walkthrough

You can access the available menu functions from `MenuRegistry` inside [`actions.js`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/1.52.1/src/vs/platform/actions/common/actions.ts):

```js
import * as actions from "monaco-editor/esm/vs/platform/actions/common/actions"
let menus = actions.MenuRegistry._menuItems
```

This will provide a list of all menu types:  i.e.
`["MenubarEditMenu", "CommandPalette", "EditorContext", ...]`

To access and modify the context menu specifically, we can find it in the menu map:

```js
let contextMenuEntry = [...menus].find(entry => entry[0]._debugName == "EditorContext")
let contextMenuLinks = contextMenuEntry[1]
```

The menu items are of type [`LinkedList`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/1.52.1/src/vs/base/common/linkedList.ts), where each `node` contains an `element` and a reference to the `prev` and `next` node, but it comes with some utility methods that make it easier to reason about.

So if you want to list all commands, you can do this:

```js
let allCommandIds = [...contextMenuLinks].map(el => el.command?.id)
```

Using that, identify the list of commands you want to pluck out ahead of time - in our case:

```js
let removableIds = [
  "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
  "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction",
]
```

Next we need to identify and remove the nodes with those ids.  The iterator returns the [`node.element`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/1.52.1/src/vs/base/common/linkedList.ts#L130), but the [`_remove()`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/1.52.1/src/vs/base/common/linkedList.ts#L100) function takes in the entire node, so we'll have to iterate a little different than before.  Here's a function that loops through all nodes and removes each if

We'll then get all the nodes we want to remove:

```js
let removeById = (list, ids) => {
  let node = list._first;
  do {
    let shouldRemove = ids.includes(node.element?.command?.id)
    if (shouldRemove) { list._remove(node) }
  } while ((node = node.next))
}
```

And then call like this:

```
removeById(contextMenuLinks, removableIds)
```

#### Demo

[image: Screenshot Example]

#### Further Reading

- [Remove 'context menu' items (not CSS) #1567](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/1567)
- [How can I customize context menu? I want to delete 'Go to definition' #1280](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/1280)
- [How to hide the “Command Palette” item from the list of actions in Monaco Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52597274/1366033)
- [How do I remove options from the contextmenu for monaco-editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62659865/1366033)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: this awnser is now outdated too, for the latest workarounds, check: https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/1567

The awnsers here are outdated, actions.MenuRegistry._menuItems seems to no longer return anything. The editor has also moved to a shadowroot breaking the css method.

The following works:

```js
const shadowroot = document.querySelector(".shadow-root-host").shadowRoot
const RemoveContextMenuIndexes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13];
for (const itemIndex of RemoveContextMenuIndexes) {
   shadowroot.querySelector(`ul.actions-container > li.action-item:nth-child(${itemIndex})`).style.display = "none";
}
```

If you have multiple editors, you will have more elements with the shadow-root-host class, thru which you would have to loop.

Answer (score 0):

#### Hide items without CSS

The following works for me and was adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65413517/2046142) by KyleMit which did not work for me as stated.

```js
import * as actions from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/platform/actions/common/actions';

const idsToRemove = ['editor.action.clipboardCopyAction', 'editor.action.clipboardCutAction'];
actions.MenuRegistry._menuItems[1] = actions.MenuRegistry._menuItems[1]
        .filter(menuItem => !menuItem.command || !idsToRemove.includes(menuItem.command.id));
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a slightly modified approach based on Nighfalls answer

- Tap into `onContextMenu` of the code editor. This will run when user opens the context menu. Before a user opens a context menu for the first time, shadow root does not exist in the DOM.
- setTimeout is necessary here, in order for the `querySelector`s to find shadow root and context menu items, after they have been added. Again, because shadow root does not exist in the DOM until user has opened the context menu once.
- Trying to set `style.display` on the action item element was causing typescript linting issues. `.remove()` on the element itself was causing a weird bug with hovering/highlighting action items further down in the menu. Ended up needing to `.remove()` the elements inside of the action item element.

```js
this.codeEditorInstance.onContextMenu(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const shadowroot = document.querySelector('.shadow-root-host')?.shadowRoot;
    if (shadowroot) {
      const RemoveContextMenuIndexes = [3];
      for (const itemIndex of RemoveContextMenuIndexes) {
        const el = shadowroot.querySelector(
          `ul.actions-container > li.action-item:nth-child(${itemIndex})`
        );
        if (el) {
          el.querySelector('a')
            ?.querySelectorAll('span')
            .forEach((s) => s.remove());
          el.querySelector('a')?.remove();
        }
      }
    }
  }, 0);
});
```

also worth mentioning that 'paste' is already removed in Firefox, which will affect which indexes you're trying to remove. so it's probably a good idea to check browser type, and remove indexes accordingly.