# How to hide the "Command Palette" item from the list of actions in Monaco Editor

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

I have been looking everywhere, Monaco docs, github, SO but there seems to be no examples as to how to hide and disable the "command palette" command from the context menu:

[image: command palette]

Any advice?

Comment: Are you sure it can be hidden without modifying the code itself?

Comment: I'm not sure, but there's a way to control what's showing on the context menu as Monaco would hide some of actions automatically when you tell it to show the code in a read only more.

Comment: **See Also**: [Disable Cut and Copy in context menu in Monaco editor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65413517/1366033)

Comment: @Stan could you let me know how you are able to see "Format Document" in the context menu for monaco ? Do I have to add it separately, I don't see it when using java as language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh well, I had no choice but to hack my way into the DOM in order to remove the "Command Palette".

It's very far from ideal and it also doesn't really disable the `F1` shortcut but it's only thing I have for now:

```js
private onContextMenu() {
    const menuItems = document.querySelector(".monaco-menu .actions-container");
    if (menuItems && menuItems.childNodes && menuItems.childNodes.length > 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < menuItems.childNodes.length; i++) {
            const menuItem = menuItems.childNodes[i];
            if (menuItem.innerText.indexOf("Command Palette") !== -1) {
                // remove "Command Pallete" item and it's separator from the menu
                menuItems.removeChild(menuItem); // the "Command Palette" item
                menuItems.removeChild(menuItems.childNodes[i - 1]); // the separator item before "Command Palette"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, which is not really much better than editing the dom.

When creating the editor, you may override the storage service. When `F1` is pressed, the storage service look for the key `commandPalette.mru.counter`. If you throw an error in this case, the command palette will not be shown.

```
monaco.editor.create(domElement, options, {
  storageService: {
    get() {},
    remove() {},
    getNumber(key: string) { if(key === 'commandPalette.mru.counter') throw new Error(); return 0; },
    getBoolean(key: string) {},
    store() {},
    onWillSaveState() {},
    onDidChangeStorage() {},
  }
```