# How do I remove options from the contextmenu for monaco-editor?

Tags: css, contextmenu, monaco-editor

I'm currently looking to find a way to remove or hide the "Go to Definition" and "Go to References" options that display when a JS file is opened in monaco-editor as part of their built-in support, in favor of including custom options to go to definition and find references.

I believe there's no public API to accomplish this, and my attempts to hide the options with CSS have been unsuccessful, so any pointers or help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: **See Also**: [Disable Cut and Copy in context menu in Monaco editor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65413517/1366033)